# RecyclerView nestedScrollingEnabled inside a FragmentContainerView with a NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a fragment called `PostsFragment` which is used on two places.

- `HomeActivity`
- `PostActivity`

In the `HomeActivity`, I am attaching `PostsFragment` and everything is going well, but, In the second activity `PostActivity`, I have in the top some components -post details- and below them, there is `FragmentContainerView` where I want to attach it again, -I want to display the related posts-.
The `PostActivity` parent's view is `NestedScrollView`.
when I set `nestedScrollingEnabled` to `true` inside `PostsFragment` the scrollbar only works on the `recyclerView` but I want to make the whole view in `PostActivity` scrollable, which doesn't work if I set `nestedScrollingEnabled` to `false`.

I did lots of searches and nothing works.

**Edit 1**:

- Here is the code of `PostActivity`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.trade.scope.ui.project.ProjectViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".ui.project.ProjectActivity">

            <com.trade.scope.ui.custom.ViewPagerPauseAble
                android:id="@+id/image_view_banner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

      

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_title_"
                style="@style/Auth.Sub"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/muller_bold"
                android:text="@string/project_request"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_text"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view_banner" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/primary_line"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text_view_title_"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view_title_"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4" />

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

- The code of `PostsFragment`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.trade.scope.ui.projects.ProjectsViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/view_holder_project" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're building a complex view, I can recommend `CoordinatorLayout` with `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and don't miss the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted your code so I am assuming this might be the case. You have to set the `nestedScrollingEnabled` to `false` for recyclerview not for NestedScrollView

Comment: `nestedScrollingEnabled` should be on your `RecyclerView` not on `FragmentContainerView`

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Put nestedScrollingEnabled programally like this:

   ```
    yourRecyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
   ```
2. Put into your recyclerview in xml file

   ```
     android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
   ```

Hope it's help you

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, but as I mentioned in the post, it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't saw it. Why you have NestedScrollView in activity xml ? Could you put it in the xml of the fragment?